# How bad is this disk?

Tags: disk, smart, gnome-disk-utility

One of my disk became super slow recently, but with no SMART errors.

1. Why is the writing so slow now?
2. How bad is it? Should I replace it?

GNOME Disks test results:

[image: gnome disks test result]

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST4000DM004-2CV104
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5425 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Oct 30 10:54:11 2023 HKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

....

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       151289776
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   096   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       211
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   050   049   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       56965298473680
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   056   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       38825 (58 73 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       211
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1 1 2
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   063   039   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 37 (Min/Max 34/41 #46)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1237
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4930
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (0 5 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   082   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       151289776
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       29774h+18m+41.265s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       171742318154
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       149227121472
```

Answer (score 1):

The write speeds you are getting on that test are as expected for that drive.  Yes, the drive is old, but traditional HDDs don't fail on a set schedule so this one may last another 5 years or may fail tomorrow.  There is nothing here to indicate a drive failure is imminent.

There is more information on this here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/dcpa91/seagate_4tb_sata_slows_down_to_a_craw/

This drive uses SMR (shingled magnetic recording).  This allows it to store more data per area on the discs but it means that writing is slower.

The way SMR works is that the data on the disc surface for adjacent tracks overlap slightly, in a pattern like shingled roofs, where the data from a given track slighly folds over one adjacent track and slightly folds *under* the other adjacent track.

What this means is that each time a small area of the disk is written to, writes are much slower.

SMR drives tend to leave a small area of the drive in CMR mode (without shingles) to accelerate writes, with writes occurring later to the regular SMR surface.  But once the CMR section of the drive fills writing slows right down.

But different SMR drives fare differently in terms of how well they accelerate writes, and they can't accelerate continuous writes after a certain point, so you tend to get the pattern that you've observed where continuous writes average out to about one third of the read speed.

Answer (score 1):

4TB of possibly un-backed up data is a lot of data to put at risk. The prices of SSDs are currently very inexpensive. This is a great opportunity to replace your aging 4TB HDD with a 4TB SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Your Seagate Barracuda green 4TB HDD is getting close to end of life with 4 1/2 years of run time on it.  It is a desktop grade drive with a slower spindle speed and a smallish cache.  The ECC recovered count is rather high which could account for the drive appearing to lag.

If it were me and if the drive had data on it that I cared about, yes I would clone the HDD to a new drive asap.